# Hi need some assistance with creating a class in Asp.Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm completely new to ASP.NET core, and currently going through a tutorial on Udemy. The instructor is using visual studio code and I've chosen to go with visual studio.

I created a ASP.NET Core Web API project, and now I'm trying to add a new class so i can start creating the first entity, However when i create the C# class and give it a name the name within the class file doesn't change, it just remains as "class1".

Does anyone know how i can resolve this?

See screenshot below:

[image: Class]

The class name here is supposed to be "AppUser" not "class1". I'm so confused this has never happened in any of my .Net Framework projects.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You can just change the name in the source.  When you attempt to save the file, the GUI will prompt if if also needs to rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you create a new Class file, you'd go through the create dialog which allows you to set the file name which will also be the name of the class. "Class1" is the generic default file name. You can also refactor (Right click > Rename or default key binding F2 with the caret on the class name definition) which Visual Studio will ask if you also want to change the file name to match.

Comment: I've done that, it gave me the option to alter the name, so i did that and pressed enter. the class name still stayed as class1. I then right clicked it  and renamed it as "AppUser" and its still remains as "public class1()"

Comment: I've changed it manually in the class file, I'm hoping that doesn't cause any errors lol

Comment: Have you tried restarting Visual Studio? Sounds like a glitch if even a rename operation is not working.

Comment: Manually changing the class name and file name won't break anything. Keeping the file name and member name in sync is purely organizational as the compiler doesn't really care what the file name is; only if it's part of the build process.

Comment: Keeping the file name and class name different will make no difference. The compiler will just read the content inside the file, in this case: AppUser. However it is a good practice to keep both file and class name exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no change from net framework to net core concerning how you name a class.
Just go to the file and rename it, then go to the code and rename if VS wont do it automatically.

It seems much more like a VS bug. Close and open it again in case the problem persist.